# Test data handling using json parsing Java

Tags: java, json, groovy

In our automation framework, we are handling the test data in the JSON file.
below is the sample file

```
{
    "Sheet1": [
        {
            "id": "1",
            "firstname": "test",
            "lastname": "last",
            "email": "jpenddreth0@census.gov",
            "gender": "female",
            "ip_address": "26.58.193.2"
        },
        {
            "id": "2",
            "firstname": "test2",
            "lastname": "last2",
            "email": "gfrediani1@senate.gov",
            "gender": "male",
            "ip_address": "229.179.4.212"
        }
    ]
}
```

first, we convert the JSON file into MapObject, from the map we will read the data.

```
def getObjectKeyValueInTheMapList(fileName,objectName,key) {
        def keyValue = []
        Map jsonMap = new LinkedHashMap() 
        jsonMap = converJsonToMapObject(fileName)
        def getKey = jsonMap.get(objectName)            
    }
```

getKey return

```
[[email:jpenddreth0@census.gov, firstname:test, gender:female, id:1, ip_address:26.58.193.2, lastname:last], [email:gfrediani1@senate.gov, firstname:test2, gender:male, id:2, ip_address:229.179.4.212, lastname:last2]]
```

from the above map, how can I get the `email` key value for `id =1`

i.e if `id = 1` then I want to read the `email / firstname /lastname`

Answer (score 0):

Check [this](http://grails.asia/groovy-map-tutorial) out. In Groovy you can define a map like this `def jsonMap = [:]` . You can get the values in many ways for example some of them: `jsonMap.email` or `jsonMap.['email']` will return `jpenddreth0@census.gov` .

Answer (score 0):

You have a list of maps and the goal is to find the map with the
`id==1`.  If you have to do that more often, then the best approach is
to shape your data in a better way to access them by `id`.

E.g. build up a map of users by `id` with something like

```
def usersById = data.collectEntries{ [it.id, it] }
```

Then `usersById[1]` will give you the map with the `id==1`.